# Does TokuDB need any regular cleanup/maintenance?

Tags: mysql, optimization, storage-engine, tokudb

PostgreSQL has `vacuum` and InnoDB has `purge`. Does TokuDB have any required maintenance/cleanup operations? I couldn't find anything in the online docs: https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-tokudb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percona has a github page on the following

- [OPTIMIZE TABLE](https://github.com/percona/tokudb-engine/wiki/Optimize-Table) (which references another [Percona Blog](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/06/28/hot-table-optimization-with-mysql/))
- [ANALYZE TABLE](https://github.com/percona/tokudb-engine/wiki/Analyze-Table)

There is lots of info explaining why.

For example, there are messages stored in non-leaf nodes of Fractal Trees. All those messages are pushed way down to leaf nodes. This simplifies retrieval of stats needed by the Query Optimizer.

Please read those links and learn way more.

Comment: Thanks very much. I actually googled "tokudb optimize tables" after I asked the question and the GitHub project wiki never came up. I didn't even know it was on GitHub. Thanks for saving me time.